# Why does "also" in German and in English denote different things?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, meaning

There are some words in the German language that may seem to be familiar to a native English speaker, but in the end, it turns out that they are so-called "false friends" and have different meanings.

For example, the word "also" in English means "too" whereas the same "also" means "thus" or "so" in German. But as we know, the two languages are both related to the Germanic group. So it can be supposed that "also" in both English and German previously had identical meanings.

So the question is: when did "also" start denoting different things in these similar languages and why did it happen? And are there any other examples of English and German words meanings of which were the same long ago but now they don't coincide anymore?

Comment: English _also_ and German _also_ are only similar on the page. This is about spelling, not language. The English word is pronounced completely differently from the German one and no one could ever confuse them unless they knew how they were spelled and thought that made some difference; but it doesn't.

Comment: @jlawler The question meanders and is a bit unclear, but this really has nothing to do with spelling. The fact that _also_ happen to be spelt exactly the same in Modern English and Modern German is both incidental and coincidental – the question might just as well have been asking about Dutch _alzo_ or Danish _altså_. What matters is that, as surmised in the question, they are cognates, made up of the same constituent parts, but with divergent meanings, in this case meaning one thing in English and another in all the other Germanic languages.

Comment: Yes, that's right.I didn't mean spelling.I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm sorry if my question sounds a bit clumsy and is a bit unclear.I did try to diliver my thought clearly:).I just wondered when the difference in meanings had appeared and why it had happened.And it's a good addition from Janus Bahs Jacquet about the rest of Germanic languages.It would be  interesting to know  why only English standed out in this case.

Comment: It's really not that far apart. The origin is _all so_ "in this way". From this you can change meaning in the direction of "accordingly, ergo", like German did, or into "in the same way, as well", like English. (But this is only my personal thinking, so I won't write an answer.)

Comment: @phipsgabler, I doubt it, the first part in *else* explains the semantics of *also* "further" much better, and it just happens to be the same root, \*h2el-, also seen in Lat. *alius* "other", whereas *all* is from PIE \*h2el-yos with a pronomial suffix.

Comment: [cont.] To which I should add that I don't deny German *also* might have been used like *all(e)* + *so* (e.g. by Luther, "Also lebte er seinen Tag"), and after *all* perhaps *so* in early English. I even know a variant pronounciation *alleso*, though without notable reference. Nevertheless, I would not exclude conflated influences for other meanings, if that's what the question more or less specificly asked about. Further comparison to *as* "like" (German *als*), seems in order, *as well*.